# Google analytics how long to show?

Tags: google-analytics

GA is reporting not installed even though i've got the script in the HEAD location as specified, should it show straight away?

I've followed the full instruction on how to do it, or do I just need to sit and wait?

Code is

```
<?php 
    require("config.php"); 
    $submitted_username = ''; 
    if(!empty($_POST)){ 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try{ 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $login_ok = false; 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
            } 
            if($check_password === $row['password']){
                $login_ok = true;
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok){ 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;  
            header("Location: main.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: main.php"); 
        } 
        else{ 
            print("Login Failed."); 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <Head> 
        <title>Fishtrends | Tightlines</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0>
        <link href = "css/css/bootstrap.css" rel = "Stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/fonts/fonta/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-5178940-4', 'fishtrends.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

    </head>
<body>


 <div class = "navbar navbar-main navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand"><b>Fishtrends</b> - Social Fish trending</a>
        <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "active"><a href ="/register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Register</li></a>
          <li class = "dropdown">
            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Login<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: px;">
                <form action="login.php" method="post"> Username:<br /> 
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
                    <br /><br /> Password:<br /> <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
                    <br /><br /> 
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" /> 
            </form> 
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="indexjumbotron">
  <h1>Be Fish social</h1>
  <p1>Add and see catch details, baits used, weights of fish plus more</p1>
</div>
<div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0 auto;width:500px">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Sign up now for Free!</B></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form name="registration" method="post" action="/register.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Userame">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputSubject" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-xs-10">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">

                <div class = "container">
                    <p class = "navbar-text pull-left">Copyright Fishtrends - 2013 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></i></p>
                    <a href = "http://www.twitter.com/fishtrends" class = "navbar-btn btn-primary btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i> Follow Us</a>
                    <p class = "navbar-text pull-right"><a href ="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> About Us</a></p>
                </div>

        </div>


            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="css/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything wrong in this code, did you tried the real time reports to clarify. If the code is installed then you can see some live traffic reports including referrals and other related info. Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

The regular reporting won't update for several hours. However, there is a [real-time tab](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#realtime/rt-overview) that should show you results immediately. On the HTML side of things, you've got a lot of missing/extra/out-of-order tags. I think this is what you are aiming for in the HTML (I did not include the PHP code since I haven't made any changes to it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Fishtrends | Tightlines</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "css/css/bootstrap.css" rel = "Stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/fonts/fonta/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-5178940-4', 'fishtrends.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "navbar navbar-main navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand"><b>Fishtrends</b> - Social Fish trending</a>
            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class = "active"><a href ="/register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Register</a></li>
                <li class = "dropdown">
                    <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Login<b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: px;">
                        <form action="login.php" method="post"> Username:<br /> 
                            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
                            <br /><br /> Password:<br /> <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
                            <br /><br /> 
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" /> 
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="indexjumbotron">
      <h1>Be Fish social</h1>
      <p>Add and see catch details, baits used, weights of fish plus more</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0 auto;width:500px">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Sign up now for Free!</b></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form name="registration" method="post" action="/register.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Userame" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputSubject" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class = "container">
            <p class = "navbar-text pull-left">Copyright Fishtrends - 2013 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></i></p>
            <a href = "http://www.twitter.com/fishtrends" class = "navbar-btn btn-primary btn pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i> Follow Us
            </a>
            <p class = "navbar-text pull-right"><a href ="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> About Us</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: THanks guys,

The realtime reporting works...I just wondered why it hadn't picked up the tracking as installed yet.

I guess it needs to be processed by our friends at Google somewhere :)

Comment: @user2932546 thanks is not necessary, marking my answer or Ishara-Shehan's answer as the solution is enough